# WinDbg cannot resolve .NET Core libraries symbols

Tags: c#, assembly, windbg, jit

I am new to WinDbg and I recently started using it to see JITed assembly code generated by the JIT compiler for C# code. (I know there are other methods as well for example sharplab.io, but still)

Following is my simple program built using .NET 6. I wanted to see JITed code for the `PrintNumber` method.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintNumber();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static void PrintNumber()
    {
        int number = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("The number is " + number);
    }
}
```

When I see the above code in Visual Studio built-in disassembler I see the following assembly code. And as you can see (I have highlighted it with a red border) Visual Studio can correctly resolve the call instruction address to the correct .NET method name which will get called.
[image: JITed code Visual studio]

But if I open the same method assembly code in WinDbg, I see the following assembly code. As I have highlighted, WinDbg is not able to resolve the call instruction to the actual .NET method name and instead just shows the address.

[image: JITed code WinDbg]

It seems like it's the issue of symbols, but cannot find a solution to this.
I have the following symbol's settings under WinDbg
[image: symbols settings]

Comment: Are you using the SOS extension and the `!u` command to disassemble?

Comment: Yes, I loaded SOS by `.loadby sos coreclr`, but still not effective. 
No, I do not use `!u` command to disassemble. I launch the executable and once run till the end I execute `!name2ee Sample!Program.PrintNumber` command to find JIT ASM code for that method.

Answer (score 0):

it appears to work here

```
0:000> !Name2EE pnum Program.PrintNumber
Module:      00007ff81d374148
Assembly:    pnum.exe
Token:       0000000006000002
MethodDesc:  00007ff81d375a10
Name:        Program.PrintNumber()
JITTED Code Address: 00007ff81d4808e0
0:000> !U /d 00007ff81d4808e0
Normal JIT generated code
Program.PrintNumber()
Begin 00007ff81d4808e0, size 72

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\pnum\pnum.cs @ 14:
>>> 00007ff8`1d4808e0 55              push    rbp
00007ff8`1d4808e1 57              push    rdi
00007ff8`1d4808e2 4883ec38        sub     rsp,38h
00007ff8`1d4808e6 488d6c2440      lea     rbp,[rsp+40h]
00007ff8`1d4808eb 488d7de0        lea     rdi,[rbp-20h]
00007ff8`1d4808ef b906000000      mov     ecx,6
00007ff8`1d4808f4 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00007ff8`1d4808f6 f3ab            rep stos dword ptr [rdi]
00007ff8`1d4808f8 833dc93cefff00  cmp     dword ptr [00007ff8`1d3745c8],0
00007ff8`1d4808ff 7405            je      00007ff8`1d480906
00007ff8`1d480901 e8cabfa25f      call    clr!JIT_DbgIsJustMyCode (00007ff8`7ceac8d0)
00007ff8`1d480906 90              nop

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\pnum\pnum.cs @ 15:
00007ff8`1d480907 c745f405000000  mov     dword ptr [rbp-0Ch],5

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\pnum\pnum.cs @ 16:
00007ff8`1d48090e 48b9a085e778f87f0000 mov rcx,offset mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsOverloaded()$##600464C <PERF> (mscorlib_ni+0x285a0) (00007ff8`78e785a0)
00007ff8`1d480918 e8131c525f      call    clr!JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP_InlineGetThread (00007ff8`7c9a2530)
00007ff8`1d48091d 488945e8        mov     qword ptr [rbp-18h],rax
00007ff8`1d480921 488b55e8        mov     rdx,qword ptr [rbp-18h]
00007ff8`1d480925 8b4df4          mov     ecx,dword ptr [rbp-0Ch]
00007ff8`1d480928 894a08          mov     dword ptr [rdx+8],ecx
00007ff8`1d48092b 488b55e8        mov     rdx,qword ptr [rbp-18h]
00007ff8`1d48092f 488b0c258036e312 mov     rcx,qword ptr [12E33680h] ("The number is ")
00007ff8`1d480937 e8e4baf55b      call    mscorlib_ni!System.String.Concat(System.Object, System.Object)$##6000550 (00007ff8`793dc420)
00007ff8`1d48093c 488945e0        mov     qword ptr [rbp-20h],rax
00007ff8`1d480940 488b4de0        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]
00007ff8`1d480944 e8570df35b      call    mscorlib_ni!System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)$##6000B79 (00007ff8`793b16a0)
00007ff8`1d480949 90              nop

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\pnum\pnum.cs @ 17:
00007ff8`1d48094a 90              nop
00007ff8`1d48094b 488d65f8        lea     rsp,[rbp-8]
00007ff8`1d48094f 5f              pop     rdi
00007ff8`1d480950 5d              pop     rbp
00007ff8`1d480951 c3              ret
```

call stack

```
0:000> !DumpStack
OS Thread Id: 0x263c (0)
Current frame: (MethodDesc 00007ff81d375a10 +0x26 Program.PrintNumber())
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
0000000000b4ed00 00007ff81d4808b4 (MethodDesc 00007ff81d375a00 +0x24 Program.Main()), calling 00007ff81d480488 (stub for Program.PrintNumber())
0000000000b4ed08 00007ff87c9a7070 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x8e, calling clr!_chkstk
0000000000b4ed40 00007ff87c9a6923 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
0000000000b4ed48 00007ff87c9a7070 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x8e, calling clr!_chkstk
0000000000b4ed80 00007ff87c9a6838 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e, calling clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal
0000000000b4ed90 00007ff87c9a73cc clr!ArgIteratorTemplate<ArgIteratorBase>::GetNextOffset+0x2c, calling clr!ArgIteratorTemplate<ArgIteratorBase>::HasRetBuffArg
0000000000b4edc0 00007ff87c9a70e8 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x102, calling clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler
0000000000b4ee10 00007ff87cb3c851 clr!MethodDesc::IsVoid+0x21, calling clr!MetaSig::IsReturnTypeVoid
0000000000b4ee30 00007ff87c9a7070 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x8e, calling clr!_chkstk
0000000000b4eec0 00007ff87cb3b210 clr!RunMain+0x25f, calling clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker
0000000000b4f060 00007ff87caa8e4f clr!Thread::SetBackground+0x9e, calling clr!ThreadSuspend::UnlockThreadStore
0000000000b4f0a0 00007ff87cb3bab7 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb7, calling clr!RunMain
0000000000b4f130 00007ff88e5fb44d ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal+0xa2d, calling ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap
0000000000b4f1e0 00007ff88e5f5ba1 ntdll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal+0x491, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0000000000b4f210 00007ff88c171a5e KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8e, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
0000000000b4f240 00007ff87cb03ade clr!AppDomain::GetFriendlyNameForDebugger+0x98, calling clr!SString::GetUnicode
0000000000b4f2a0 00007ff88e5f47b1 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x51, calling ntdll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal
0000000000b4f2e0 00007ff87c9a5829 clr!EEHeapFreeInProcessHeap+0x45, calling KERNEL32!HeapFreeStub
0000000000b4f320 00007ff87cb049cb clr!MulticoreJitManager::AutoStartProfile+0x38, calling clr!CLRConfig::GetConfigValue
0000000000b4f330 00007ff87ca50c3e clr!SBuffer::Set+0x46, calling clr!memcpy
0000000000b4f350 00007ff87cb3c73f clr!PEFileSecurityDescriptor::`vector deleting destructor'+0x2f, calling clr!operator delete
0000000000b4f390 00007ff87cb3b96b clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x643, calling clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod
0000000000b4f3c0 00007ff87c9a600d clr!EEConfig::GetConfiguration_DontUse_+0x36, calling clr!GetThread
0000000000b4f580 00007ff87c9c8a5c clr!Alloc+0x1af
0000000000b4f5d0 00007ff87c9aaec9 clr!HndAssignHandle+0x25, calling clr!HndWriteBarrier
0000000000b4f600 00007ff87caa8d64 clr!HndCreateHandle+0x8c, calling clr!StressLog::LogOn
0000000000b4f610 00007ff87caa9799 clr!GCHandleManager::CreateGlobalHandleOfType+0x39
0000000000b4f640 00007ff87caa9dd6 clr!CreateGlobalHandleCommon+0x4e, calling clr!DiagHandleCreated
0000000000b4f670 00007ff87cb08a35 clr!AppDomain::SetupSharedStatics+0xf5, calling clr!ErectWriteBarrier
0000000000b4f690 00007ff87cb2d129 clr!SafeHandle::Init+0x41, calling clr!MethodDesc::GetSlot
0000000000b4f6c0 00007ff87cb335b2 clr!EEStartupHelper+0x822, calling clr!CLRException::HandlerState::CleanupTry
0000000000b4f730 00007ff88e5f5ba1 ntdll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal+0x491, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0000000000b4f930 00007ff87cb32d65 clr!EEStartup+0x15, calling clr!EEStartupHelper
0000000000b4f990 00007ff87cb3b2b4 clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f, calling clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod
0000000000b4fa00 00007ff87cb3b00d clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xb2, calling clr!ExecuteEXE
0000000000b4fa60 00007ff88e6207b0 ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error+0x40, calling ntdll!_security_check_cookie
0000000000b4fa90 00007ff87cb3c1f4 clr!CorExeMain+0x14, calling clr!_CorExeMainInternal
0000000000b4fad0 00007ff87d6e8c01 mscoreei!CorExeMain+0x112
0000000000b4fb00 00007ff881741560 MSCOREE!GetShimImpl+0x18, calling MSCOREE!InitShimImpl
0000000000b4fb10 00007ff88174acd2 MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x102, calling KERNEL32!GetProcAddressStub
0000000000b4fb30 00007ff88174ac42 MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x72, calling MSCOREE!guard_dispatch_icall_nop
0000000000b4fb60 00007ff88d6f7034 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14, calling KERNEL32!guard_dispatch_icall_nop
0000000000b4fb90 00007ff88e622651 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21, calling ntdll!guard_dispatch_icall_nop
```

Comment: Any troubleshooting steps that you want me to perform!? I am ready to follow!

Comment: I have this version installed Debugger client version: 1.2111.9001.0 and Debugger engine version: 10.0.22473.1005

Comment: i did nothing special your code was missing a using System: added it compiled as is with csc -debug blah.cs as x64 opened it in windbg added an sxe ld:clr  when clr was loaded used .load sos ;!sosflush;!name2ee blah foo.bar  thats it i was using the legacy windbg on winx

Comment: I tried the same but it still not working. BTW I am using WinDBG preview which is available here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

I even checked the symbols files, `system.console.pdb` is there, but still, somehow I am not getting the method name instead it shows call instruction. Can you give try with Windbg preview for the same? So that we can figure out is somewhat version issue or what!

Comment: The output comes from a .NET Framework memory dump. I have the same issue as @ShreyasJejurkar with a .NET 6 memory dump. It's just a theory but I suspect that when tiered JIT was introduced, SOS wasn't updated to know how to navigate the new stubs.

Comment: thanks kevin for commenting back i didnt have windbgx to check if thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated by Kevin Gosse, I guess SOS is not able to find symbols when TiredCompilation is on. We need to disable it (maybe do it only on the development machine) by setting the env variable `COMPlus_TieredCompilation` to 0.
I tried and then WinDbg (more specifically SOS) was able to load symbols files correctly and can able to resolve the method call address.

Sadly, this has not been documented well anywhere. Issues like this can heavily destroy a newcomer's motivation.

More info => https://twitter.com/ShreyasJejurkar/status/1496160952479551492

Thanks, Kevin Gosse for the great help!